# JavaScript in button onclick not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a webpage (ASP.NET C#) that has a button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnHide" runat="server" OnClick="HidePanel" Text="Hide"/>
```

and I'm doing a JavaScript alert like:

```
public void HidePanel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"Hello","<script type=text/javascript> alert('Hello') </script>");
}
```

If I modify the function to not have `object sender` and `EventArgs e` then I can call it from `Page_Load`, and it works fine, I get the alert.

As written above I expect to see the alert when I click the button, but it's not happening. I'm sure it's something obvious, but I don't see it.

Comment: I am using OnClick because there is a lot more that has to happen such as checking connectivity and current session with a 3rd party reservation system we use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the code to register the JavaScript code and instead do this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnHide" runat="server" 
   OnClick="HidePanel" Text="Hide" OnClientClick="alert('Hello');" 
   UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

This:

```
UseSubmitBehavior="false"
```

will cause the button to fire the client-side script, and it will run the server-side code (post-back).

Answer (score 3):

Use `OnClientClick` instead of `OnClick`. And add a `return false` to avoid a postback on the page.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnHide" runat="server" OnClientClick="alert('Hello'); return false;" Text="Hide"/>
```

Comment: There's a lot of steps that have to happen in the server side.  If I do this can I get it to run my server scripts after the js handles the click event if I don't have an onclick?

Comment: Just add the OnClick back and add your server side code on the OnClick method. But leave the alert on the OnClientClick and remove the return false so that the page postsback and executes your server side code. This will make the alert popup and when you click ok the page will postback and your server side will execute.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using,
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "nameOfScript", scriptString);

I'ved used that before in a click event.

edit:
I can't edit posts yet, but your code works fine for me as well.

And depending on the situation he might want to do some server side stuff as well on the click event, or build up the script dynamically.

Edit:
If you already registered a script with the same name, it won't run, eg.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Hello", "<script type=text/javascript> var i = 0;</script>");
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Hello", "<script type=text/javascript> alert('other hello') </script>");
```